# Working on a matrix inverter and my exponential loop is not working for some reason

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, matrix, matrix-inverse

I am working on a matrix inverter and I have it almost done but for some reason the function that is supposed to raise the matrix to a certain value is not working, I have isolated the function on its own and it has worked just fine. But for some reason is not working in this program

**Isolated**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void printano(double a[3][3])
{
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << setw(12) << a[i][j] << "  ";
    cout << endl;
    }
}

void powernator(double r[][3],double B[][3], int p)
{
    double temp[3][3] = { {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} };
    int n = 3;

  for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
{
    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
    {
      r[b][d] = B[b][d];
    }
}

  for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++)
  {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
    {
      for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
      {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
          sum += B[b][k] * r[k][d];
        }
        temp[b][d] = sum;
        sum = 0;
      }
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
    {
      for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
      {
        r[b][d] = temp[b][d];
      }
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
double B[3][3] = { {1, 2, 3} , {4, 5, 6} , {7, 8, 9} };
double r[3][3] = { {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} };

powernator(r,B,3);

printano(r);
}
```

**The actual code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

void multiplinator(double x[][3], double y[][3], double z[][3]) //At the end I double check to make sure the value is correct as it needs to equal the identity matrix
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                    for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                    {
                            z[i][j] += x[i][k] * y[k][j];
                    }
            }
    }
}

void printinator(double a[3][3]) //prints a matrix
{
for(int i=0; i<=2; i++)
    {
    for(int j=0; j<=2; j++)
        cout << fixed << setprecision(4) << setw(12) << a[i][j] << "  ";
    cout << endl;
    }
        cout << endl;
}

void sub(double as[3][3], double in[][3], double B[][3]) //Matrix subtraction
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            B[i][j] = in[i][j] - as[i][j];
}

void powernator(double r[][3],double B[][3], int p) //Array which is supposed to raise a matrix to a certain power
{
    double temp[3][3] = { {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} };
    int n = 3;

  for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
{
    for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
    {
      r[b][d] = B[b][d];
    }
}

  for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++)
  {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
    {
      for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
      {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
          sum += B[b][k] * r[k][d];
        }
        temp[b][d] = sum;
        sum = 0;
      }
    }
    for (int b = 0; b < n; b++)
    {
      for (int d = 0; d < n; d++)
      {
        r[b][d] = temp[b][d];
      }
    }
  }
}

void gettem(double r[][3], double in[][3], double inm[][3]) //Supposed to return the final value, aka, the inverse matrix, as a^-1 = I + B^1 +B^2...
{
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            inm[i][j] = in[i][j] + r[i][j];
    }


}

int main()
{
double a[3][3] = { {1./2, 1, 0} , {0, 2./3, 0} , {-1./2, -1, 2./3} };
double as[3][3] ={ {1./2, 1, 0} , {0, 2./3, 0} , {-1./2, -1, 2./3} };
double in[3][3] = { {1, 0, 0} , {0, 1, 0} , {0, 0, 1} };

double B[3][3] = { {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} };
double r[3][3] = { {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} };

double inm[3][3] = { {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} };
double z[3][3] = { {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 0} };


cout << "\n\t\t    Original : " << endl;
    printinator(a);

sub(as,in,B);

printinator(B);
powernator(r,B,2);
printinator(r); //testing the power function, not working

/*for(int n = 0; n < 20; n++) //Final part of the code commented out for debug, this loop is meant to add up B^n where n is from 1 - 20
{

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            r[i][j] += B[i][j];
}

gettem(r,in,inm);

cout << "\n\t\t    Inverse: " << endl;
printinator(inm);
multiplinator(as,a,z);
cout << "\n\t\t    multi: " << endl;
printinator(z);

*/

}
```

Comment: Please explain in detail what "*not working in this program*" means. Does your program not compile? Does it segfault? Does it not produce the expected output? Please include any error messages and output of the program, as well as the output you expect it to give.

Comment: Why would you need to *raise a matrix to a number* in order to find it's inverse? Have a look a [this](https://github.com/md-akhi/Inverse-matrix/blob/master/Inverse-matrix.cpp).

Comment: I had something like that but my Prof wants it done this way. And yes the output is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Isolated Code

```
powernator(r,B,3);
```

Actual Code.

```
powernator(r,B,2);
```

parameter `p` is differ..

Comment: Yes, but you can change it and the isolated one is correct whereas the one in the code returns all zeroes.

Comment: @Dumbquestionsman  The input matrix B is differ..  Use same ```main()```, compare the result..